# How to say "Welcome to England"?

Tags: vocabulário, tradução-inglês

We're welcoming a Portuguese flatmate tomorrow who's moving in, and want to put some nice bunting up. What would be an appropriate phrase to use?

Comment: Which phrase did you go for in the end?

Answer (score 8):

**Bem-vindo** if he's a boy, **bem-vinda** if she's a girl, is Portuguese for **welcome**. So, the male version only:

> *Welcome to England* is **Bem-vindo à Inglaterra** (*)
>
> *Welcome Home* is **Bem-vindo a Casa**

If you want a touch of self-deprecating humour you might want

> *Welcome to [Perfidious Albion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfidious_Albion)*: **Bem-vindo à Pérfida Álbion**

Not everyone will know *pérfida Álbion* though. So you may want to go for

> *Welcome to the Land of the bifes*: **Bem-vindo à Terra dos Bifes**

**Bife** is of course a mildly jocular Portuguese nickname for an English person. It literally means (meat) steak, and comes from the English word **beef**. The food connection notwithstanding *bife*, unlike *frog* in the case of a French person, is not derogatory.

(*) **À** or **a** in Portugal, **à** only in Brazil.

Comment: Jacinto, why a capital C in casa ?

Comment: @Centaurus Existe no português o ditado «Onde fores…», não é?  :-)

Comment: @guifa  Não entendi. Não conheço nenhum ditado começando com "onde fores"

Comment: @Centaurus Em inglês dezimos «When in Rome, do as the Romans», em castelhano é «Donde fueres, haz lo que vieres» (Onde fores, faz o que vires).  Em inglês, escrevemos essas palavras como maiúscula inicial.

Comment: @Centaurus ah claro, o português não usaria o modelo ibérico. «Em Roma sê romano»

Comment: @guifa  We're not in Rome. A Roman has come to us with a question.

Comment: @Centaurus My capital first letters again :). I'm imagining it written on a banner, so you may want to capitalise the words as in a title.

Comment: @guifa in Portugal, we say "na terra onde fores ter, faz como vires fazer". But how is this saying relevant to the answer?

Comment: @Jacinto, seguramente queres dizer "Bem-vindo à Inglaterra"?

Comment: Não, na verdade, eu digo _vou a/gostei de/vivi em Inglaterra_. Embora seja capaz de dizer _a Inglaterra joga hoje_... ou _Portugal joga hoje com a Inglaterra_. Chama-me incoerente. Para Inglaterra, França e Itália, o artigo em Portugal é opcional (ou seja, de facto o artigo uma vezes é usado, outras não).

Comment: @Jacinto   Não vejo como omitir o artigo definido no caso acima.  Veja como soa mal quando usamos uma palavra no masculino:  Vou a Japão, a Brasil, a México.  Acho que o artigo é obrigatório e, sendo obrigatório, haverá crase quando o país for do gênero feminino. Em ptBR poucos países são netros em gênero (em Cuba, em Barbados, em Israel, em Andorra, em Angola, em Moçambique, etc.  A maioria tem gênero e a Inglaterra é um deles.  Certa vez ouvi dizer "quando eu morava em França", mas isso caiu no desuso e falar assim no Brasil seria pedantismo.

Comment: @Centaurus Em Portugal é facultativo com Inglaterra. Pode dizer-se tanto "Bem-vindo a Inglaterra" como "Bem-vindo à Inglaterra". O mesmo com "França" e Itália. Já "Espanha" não pode levar artigo.

Comment: @Centaurus Em Portugal não se diz _à Espanha_ nem _na Espanha_, mas diz-se _a Espanha joga_... e _o jogo com a Espanha!_ Somos uma cambada de incoerentes!

Comment: @Artefacto Vê se concordas com o comentário acima.

Comment: @Centaurus Ou melhor, pode dizer-se _a Espanha joga_... e _o jogo com a Espanha_. O artigo pode ser omitido nestes casos também. Em Portugal **a** e **à** têm sons diferentes; normalmente não nos atrapalhamos com eles.

Comment: @Jacinto É verdade. A Espanha joga, o Brasil joga, mas Moçambique/Angola/Cabo Verde/São Tomé jogam. Mas vivo em Espanha, não na Espanha; vou a Espanha, não à Espanha.

Comment: Mesmo no caso de França, Itália e Inglaterra, mais facilmente uso o artigo como sujeito ou com **com**: _a França joga com a Itália_ do que com outras preposições: _fui de Itália para Inglaterra com escala em França_.

Answer (score 5):

I'm probably too late, but if you don't know the gender of your flatmate, and you think "Inglaterra" is hard to pronounce, you can simply say:

> Boas vindas!

In a more formal way (treating the person as an important guest) and resembling [Jacinto's examples](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/a/1309/156) you can add "seja":

> Seja bem-vindo à Inglaterra!

You may want to pronounce:

- each **a** as the *uh* sound in "d**uh**";
- the **o** as you'd pronounce the *o* in "n**o**";
- the **i** as the *ee* sound in "p**i**ss";
- the last **s** of each word as the *sh* in "**sh**muck";
- the **rr** sound as a guttural sound and you definitely want to [sound like this girl](https://youtu.be/1GqO_Cn9cjQ?t=17) when she pronounces the words "**r**ato", "**R**oma", "ca**rr**o" or "cacho**rr**o";
- the **e** sound as the *eh* sound in "m**eh**";
- the **j** as a "**gee**";
- the **à** sound as the *ah* sound in "n**ah**".

[Here's how "boas vindas!" sounds](https://youtu.be/dsIoirjfmBA?t=30), and you can say this sentence anytime a person returns back from somewhere, as you'd say "welcome back".

If you truly want to buff up your welcome, I also recommend to follow [Jacinto's suggestion](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/a/1309/156) and replace "Inglaterra" by "**Terra dos Bifes**" or even better: "**Bifolândia**" (pronounced as: beef'olandeeuh).

Btw, how did your flatmate react?

Comment: That doesn't sounds right it looks like you are giving welcome to the subject "Inglaterra".

Comment: @JorgeB. you are right, "boas vindas" is more commonly used with the subject to be welcomed. I.e. "boas vindas à Inglaterra" would be more similar to "welcome England" (welcoming the country itself). Edited the answer.